# docker version of composer playground is not able to connect to local hlf 1.0.0-alpha runtime

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I followed the hyperledger composer quick start for hyperledger fabric 1.0.0-alpha and have a working hyperledger fabric running locally.
I downloaded the latest (0.7.2) docker image for composer playground and started it as per the docker hub instructions but I am unable to connect to my locally running hlfv1 when I define the urls of

```
"type": "hlfv1",
"orderers": [
    "grpc://localhost:7050"
],
"ca": "http://localhost:7054",
"peers": [
    {
        "requestURL": "grpc://localhost:7051",
        "eventURL": "grpc://localhost:7053"
    },
    {
        "requestURL": "grpc://localhost:7056",
        "eventURL": "grpc://localhost:7058"
    }
],
"keyValStore": "/home/ubuntu/.hfc-key-store",
"channel": "mychannel",
"mspID": "Org1MSP",
"deployWaitTime": "300",
"invokeWaitTime": "100"
```

The UI hangs with a spinning icon in the button.
What's the problem here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to docker-compose starting the hyperledger fabric runtimes within there own network. If you followed the quick start guide then the network it would have created is called "hlfv1_default". 
When you start another docker container, unless you explicitly say which network you want it to be part of it will be added to "bridge". This isolates the environments from each other. 
You can see the networks using the command

```
docker network ls
```

In order to get composer docker containers talking to your local fabric you need to ensure that it is connected to local fabric network. For example if your local fabric is on network `hlfv1_default` then you can connect the composer-playground to that network using the command

```
docker run --network hlfv1_default --name composer-playground --publish 8080:8080 --detach hyperledger/composer-playground
```

Once you have done that you can create a connection profile however, you cannot use localhost, you have to use the hostnames created by docker-compose. For the quick start currently which uses hlf v1.0.0-alpha (as opposed to alpha2) you would use a connection profile that looks like

```
"type": "hlfv1",
"orderers": [
    "grpc://orderer0:7050"
],
"ca": "http://ca0:7054",
"peers": [
    {
        "requestURL": "grpc://peer0:7051",
        "eventURL": "grpc://peer0:7053"
    },
    {
        "requestURL": "grpc://peer1:7056",
        "eventURL": "grpc://peer1:7058"
    }
],
"keyValStore": "/home/composer/.hfc-key-store",
"channel": "mychannel",
"mspID": "Org1MSP",
"deployWaitTime": "300",
"invokeWaitTime": "100"
```

note the replacement of localhost with the service names from the docker-compose file used to launch the local fabric: 'orderer0', 'ca0', 'peer0', 'peer1'.

A useful tool is the `docker network inspect` command which will show you what containers are using that network.

Comment: you were right, they were using different networks. However, the problem stays the same: "The UI hangs with a spinning icon in the button"

Comment: Was there anything output in the playground logs 
`docker logs composer-playground` ?

Comment: This error from logs looks relevant:
0|composer | Error: Connect Failed
0|composer |     at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:201:19)
0|composer |     at ClientDuplexStream._readsDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:169:8)
0|composer |     at readCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:229:12)

Comment: Next line: PM2        | App [composer-playground] with id [0] and pid [74], exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]

Comment: That is definitely a comms problem in your case. There is also a known issue where the UI appears to hang saying deploying sample network.